# How to sum numbers From a CSV File and output it to TXT File In Java?

Tags: java, csv, netbeans, txt

I have CSV flie in flie like this

```
5,4,3,2,1

1,2,3,4,5

6,7,8,9,10
```

and I want to sum all number and I have to get output is TXT file

Comment: What should the output file contain? Should it have three rows with the sum of every element in the respective row in the source file or a single number?

Comment: Sum each data line in file or sum ALL file lines?

Comment: @AddeusExMachina output just sum of number

Comment: @DevilsHnd  sum ALL file lines

Comment: I'm really sorry with my English and I'm beginner with Java if I made you guys confused. sometime I don't know how to explain my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path source = Path.of("src/sample.csv");
    Path dest = Path.of("src/result.txt");

    try (var s = Files.lines(source);
        var d = Files.newBufferedWriter(dest)) {

      int sum = s.map(f -> f.split(","))
          .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
          .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
          .sum();

      d.write(String.valueOf(sum));
    }
  }
```